# Having 2 synchronous videos in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, html, reveal.js

I am trying to have 2 videos plays synchronously together in Reveal.js.
The goal is to have 2 (or multiple videos) in the same slide.

I want one video to be in the foreground and one in the background (hidden by the first video).
Both videos start as the slide is shown, but when I go to the next slide I want the video in the foreground to get invisible and the second video to show.

This could also work in another way. It does not have to be 2 videos on the same slide.
Another way I imagine this could work is when I have the first slide I want the same video time be put on the second video. So if the first slide is shown for 20 seconds, skip the first 20 second on the video in the next slide.

I have been using data-background-video before, but I fear that this will not work for what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.